# On feeds, how to access ORGANIZER source

Tags: feeds

I'm importing an iCal feed using iCal Parser. I've actually tried a few other parsers including Date API iCal parser, iCalCreator parser, but every one seems to have the same set of sources. How can I access all the other fields in the feed, specifically, the ORGANIZER: `ORGANIZER;CN=name@email.com:mailto:name@email.com`?

I've tried to hook into `hook_feeds_parser_sources_alter`, and setting up a new callback function. Like this:

```
/**
* Implements hook_feeds_parser_sources_alter().
*/
function my_hook_feeds_parser_sources_alter(&$sources, $content_type) {
$sources['field_importer_reference'] = array(
'name' => t('Organizer'),
'description' => t('The name of the organizer.'),
'callback' => 'my_hook_get_organizer',
);
}
function my_hook_get_organizer(FeedsSource $source) {
dpm($source->CN);// this doesn't do anything...
return $source->CN;
}
```

I get this message when I try to import: `Date iCal does not recognize the "Organizer" Mapping Source, and must skip it.`

Answer (score 1):

In writing the question I came across the answer and want to share. I was using the wrong hook. Instead I used:

```
function my_hook_date_ical_mapping_sources_alter(&$sources) {
// Add the "ORGANIZER" iCal property to the mapping sources.
$sources['ORGANIZER'] = array(
'name' => t('Organizer'),
'description' => t('The ORGANIZER property.'),
'date_ical_parse_handler' => 'parseTextProperty',
);
// Add "ORGANIZER:CN" parameter to the mapping sources.
$sources['ORGANIZER:CN'] = array(
'name' => t('Organizer: CN'),
'description' => t("The CN parameter of the ORGANIZER property: the organizer's Common Name."),
'date_ical_parse_handler' => 'parsePropertyParameter',
);
}
```

Note that I'm pulling both the Contact's Name and the mailto field.

This is a hook provided by the `date_ical` module. I basically copied the example found there.